# Angular Plotly test TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') PlotlyComponent.createFigure

Tags: angular, plotly, jasmine, plotly.js

i am having an issue running the tests file for my page, my da

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
    at PlotlyComponent.createFigure (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/angular-plotly.js/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/angular-plotly.js.js:285:21)
    at PlotlyComponent.call [as ngOnDestroy] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/angular-plotly.js/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm2015/angular-plotly.js.js:195:29)
    at executeOnDestroys (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:6537:32)
    at cleanUpView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:6438:9)
    at destroyViewTree (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:6264:21)
    at destroyLView (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:6416:9)
    at RootViewRef.destroy (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:13512:9)
    at ComponentRef.destroy (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/core.mjs:13958:23)
    at ComponentFixture.destroy (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2015/testing.mjs:228:31)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/pages/graph.component.spec.ts:163:17)
```

i am using PlotlyViaWindowModule, when i start ng serve the plot is working correctly without any issues but i cant run the test

```
describe('GraphComponent', () => {
    let component: GraphComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<GraphComponent>;
    let debugElement: DebugElement;

    beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
              ... , 
              PlotlyComponent
            ], 
            providers:  [
                 ...,
                PlotlyService, 
                { provide: MyPlotService, useClass: myPlotServiceMock},
            ],   
            imports: [
                ...
                PlotlyViaWindowModule,
            ]

beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(GraphComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        debugElement = fixture.debugElement;

    
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('shoud create the app', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    })
   <app-plotly [data]="traceData"></app-plotly>
traaceData is defined and shows data when console logged
```